# AppInsights query to display RPS of each request

Tags: azure-application-insights

Below Application Insights query gets response time of each request.
Can we extend above query and also display RequestPerSeconds for each request ?

```
// this query calculates request duration percentiles and count by name
let start=datetime("2021-04-13T18:35:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2021-04-13T18:52:00.000Z");
let timeGrain=5m;
let dataset=requests
    // additional filters can be applied here
    | where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
    | where client_Type != "Browser"
;
dataset
// change 'operation_Name' on the below line to segment by a different property
| summarize count_=sum(itemCount), avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99) by operation_Name
// calculate duration percentiles and count for all requests (overall)
| union(dataset
    | summarize count_=sum(itemCount), avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99)
    | extend operation_Name="Overall")

Output
Operation_Name, count_, avg_duration, percentiles_duration_50, percentiles_duration_95, percentiles_duration_99
Request1,15,2.1,2.3,2.3,2.5
Request2, 10, 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.2
```

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: What's the meaning of `RequestPerSeconds for each request` sir?

Comment: I meant throughput/RPS of each API call. 
RPS = Count of Total Requests / Total Duration (in sec)
Above query displays
OperationName, TotalCount, AverageResponseTime_Ms
API1,           20,         1.5
API2,           30,         2

I am trying to get below output with additional column(RPS)
OperationName, TotalCount, AverageResponseTime_Ms, RPS
API1,           120,         1.5                    1   [i.e 120(TotalCount)/120(TotalDuration-Diff of start and end time)]
API2,           240,         2   ,   2   [i.e 240(TotalCount)/120(TotalDuration-Diff of start and end time)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, `RequestPerSeconds` means `request total counts / total seconds`,

Based on your query, you can add

`req_count_per_sec = todecimal(sum(itemCount))/todecimal(datetime_diff('second',end,start))`

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstood in some place, pls feel free to let me know, thanks in advance sir : )

Comment: HI Tiny, Thanks for your valuable inputs. appreciate your help.

Comment: @Anil Kumar It's my pleasure.